# How to avoid problems when deploying C++ (MPI) at an HPC

Tags: c++, mpi, hpc

I am a researcher and I am working with optimization problems.

In this way, I am planning to use a HPC (C++ with MPI) which I can access through SSH. I already checked their modules and it has some compilers as Intel.

So my question is, how could I start to program and develop everything in a way that it will be easier to run it on the HPC minimizing future possible problems?

Does I have to develop my program with the same compiler that they have there? It would help? Or just compiling for Linux would be ok? This kind of questions...

Comment: Off-topic (since unrelated to code you are showing in your question) and much too broad. You could install Linux on your laptop and compile for *standard C++14* using a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler. You could (re)compile your code on the supercomputer. Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask (but you still need to give a *lot* more details). And you might also even run the compiler and the debugger (or even your editor) thru `ssh` on the supercomputer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : I disagree. This is a best-practice type of question common for new HPC users. In particular, your suggestion to work locally with the recent C++14/GCC/Clang might not be correct. HPC centers normally use custom compilers (Intel or even IBM) that might not be frequently updated and might not follow the recent standard. Furthermore, if the code depends on external libraries, they might be outdated as well. The question might be formulated better, but IMO it's valid for the general stack exchange.

Comment: @angmo: But SO is for questions related to *shown* source code, often with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I see plenty of questions under [tag:production], or [tag:deployment], most of them lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should compile the stuff at target machine. Simply ssh there and try to compile and run simple MPI application

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int rank;
    int world;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world);
    printf("Hello: rank %d, world: %d\n",rank, world);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Just try to compile and run it

```
mpicc -o hello ./hello.c
mpirun -np 2 ./hello
```

Then, you should get familiar with submission system they have there. It is used for submitting your jobs. There are different solutions and the best way is to ask support how to prepare job description and how to submit it.

Then, all you have to do is to properly organize your code and develop application. I suggest to get familiar with this one:

Ian Foster, Designing and Building Parallel Programs, http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am planning to develop it using eclipse and boost library. Do you think that I would have to make a makefile project or could I use an normal eclipse project? I mean, I would have to compile the code through SSH? And if I would have to compile there, how could I include the boost libraries at my project?

Comment: If you want to debug locally, I suggest to install libraries (at your local machine) that are used at HPC (from sources, the same version). Create Make/CMake files that will compile your code at local machine or at remote one. I guess you might get some surprises anyway, so I suggest to get familiar with gdb/idbc :)

Comment: I suggest to develop&debug locally, but verify on the HPC center as often as possible (submitting small-scale jobs on dozens of nodes). One of the biggest caveats of working with HPC code are the external libraries. You might not be able to recreate the target environment locally (HPC center might use custom, platform-specific compilers or comm libraries - which might not be compatible with the latest/greatest boost versions).